# Select parents of severel elements

Tags: jquery

Ok i have this expression:

```
 if($('#inputBez, #inputCode, #inputSeite, #inputLokal').hasClass("has-success")){
              $("#new_imagedocu").submit();
            }
```

How you can see i check if the elements have the class `has-success`. Actually it wont work because i notice that the parent elements have  the class `has-success` and not the elements itself so how can i select the parents?

I mean this wont work: Right?

```
 if($('#inputBez.parent(), #inputCode.parent()...
```

Another problem i encounterd is that the if statement is true as soon as one elemt has the class! But i want to check if all elemts have the class! I would write that as:

```
 if($('#inputBez').parent().has_class("has-success") && $('#inputCode').parent().has_class("has-success")...
```

### Html

```
<div class="col-sm-2 form-group has-success">
    <input id="inputCode" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Code"></input> 
</div>
```

How can i shorten that? Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you show the HTML, where your inputBez is and which parents you wish to select?

Comment: Also you jQuery above seems to be missing some `'` and `)`

Comment: `<div class="col-sm-2 form-group has-success">

    <input id="inputCode" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Code"></input>

</div>`

Comment: Could you do the reverse?  Check that the a parent container with the class 'has-success' also contains a child with the Id you believe it should?

Comment: Nope, not helped, still don't get the question

Comment: Sorry @Liam i want to check the divs with col-sm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the parents all the target elements using `$('#inputBez, #inputCode, #inputSeite, #inputLokal').parent()` then check whether is there an element without the class `has-success`

```
if ($('#inputBez, #inputCode, #inputSeite, #inputLokal').parent().not(".has-success").length == 0) {
    $("#new_imagedocu").submit();
}
```

or check all 4 parents has the class `has-success`

```
if ($('#inputBez, #inputCode, #inputSeite, #inputLokal').parent(".has-success").length == 4) {
    $("#new_imagedocu").submit();
}
```